# Change cell with a website as text into a link (Not using the =Hyperlink function)

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I've created a user-form for a company to enter preferred products, included is the product's website. I had it set up where the website would just be entered as normal text, but the automatic feature in Excel that registers when a cell contains a website didn't turn the text into an active hyperlink.
I was able to get help from Tim Williams on stack overflow to create a hyperlink, but the =Hyperlink function treats https://www.google.com different from www.google.com which could be resolved with more code, but I'd prefer to use less code if possible.

If I double click on the cell (with no =Hyperlink) as if to add text and then exit the cell it turns the link into a hyperlink.

What VBA code do I need to turn data entered in a text-box and submitted via a user-form into a hyperlink in the cell on the sheet?

Below is my current code;

```
Private Sub ComboBoxDivision_Change()

Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber = ""
Me.ComboBoxSpecsName = ""
Select Case Me.ComboBoxDivision
    Case "DIVISION 02 - EXISTING CONDITIONS"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.RowSource = "D02_Number"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.RowSource = "D02_Name"

    Case "DIVISION 03 - CONCRETE"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.RowSource = "D03_Number"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.RowSource = "D03_Name"

    Case "DIVISION 04 - MASONRY"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.RowSource = "D04_Number"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.RowSource = "D04_Name"    
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxSpecsNumber_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
  With ComboBoxSpecsNumber
    ComboBoxSpecsName.ListIndex = .ListIndex
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxSpecsName_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
  With ComboBoxSpecsName
    ComboBoxSpecsNumber.ListIndex = .ListIndex
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
If Me.ComboBoxDivision.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a Division.", vbExclamation, "Product_Information_Form"
Me.ComboBoxDivision.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a Specs Number or Name.", vbExclamation, "Product_Information_Form"
Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a Specs Name or Name.", vbExclamation, "Product_Information_Form"
Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

Sub AddLink(c As Range, text As String)
    If Len(text) > 0 Then
        c.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & text & """)"
    Else
        c.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub

Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("FormData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("FormData").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.ComboBoxDivision.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
AddLink .Offset(RowCount, 3), Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss")
End With

Select Case Me.ComboBoxDivision
Case "DIVISION 02 - EXISTING CONDITIONS"
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Div-02")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("a" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
AddLink ws.Range("c" & LastRow), Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value

Case "DIVISION 03 - CONCRETE"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-03")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("a" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
AddLink ws.Range("c" & LastRow), Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value

Case "DIVISION 04 - MASONRY"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-04")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("a" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
AddLink ws.Range("c" & LastRow), Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value


End Select

Unload Product_Information_Form
Start_Form.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, but as someone who is relatively new to VBA, I still don't understand all of it.  Having someone show where my code is wrong helps me learn faster for the specific question I have.